# Resampling of two data sets of different length in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, sampling, resampling

I have two vectors: sensorA of length 927 and sensorB of length 1250. I would like to make them of the same length. The resample() function in MATLAB is very noisy at the edges and I need atleast reasonably good accuracy throughout.

I understand that resampling can be done by interpolation, but how do I implement it in the most efficient way. I need to stretch 927 to 1250 as uniformly as possible.

I was wondering if I could do something like this:

1. I need 333 new samples in the shorter vector. So for every 3 values, I insert the average (midpoint) of two consecutive values in between then. => 309 samples inserted
2. For the remaining I insert again for every 38 samples (927/(333-309))

Does this make sense? I still won't be able to get an exact interpolation. Is there any other function that I could use? (besides `interp()` because it requires an integral resampling rate?)

Comment: Is there a reason that interp1() will not work for you? You can ask it to provide interpolation to an arbitrary set of output points. http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/interp1.html

Comment: if you give it a better title, I'll give you a +1, eg "re-sampling 2 data sets to give the same length in Matlab"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a signal-processing view, you should NOT just insert a sample every 3 values.  That would be non-uniform stretching and would ruin your signal.  The [resample](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/resample.html) function is what you want.  Try changing the parameters for n and/or beta.  You may need to pad your signal as described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4BPE5Q/?solution=1-4BPE5Q) to reduce the edge effects.

Answer (score 0):

Resampling a bandlimited signal is identical to interpolation using an infinite Sinc interpolation kernel, and pretty close to windowed Sinc interpolation with a well chosen window.  See this [Stanford CCRMA website](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/resample/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

To do interpolation, use [interp1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/interp1.html). For your purposes, this might be good enough, though, as stated above, resample is the correct thing to do.